# What could cause a Gemcrafter to stay inside his workshop for a long time and eventually die, while still being "undiscovered"?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

My gemcrafter locked himself inside of his workshop for a suspiciously long time. Eventually, he became "missing" and his yet-to-be-discovered corpse was releasing clouds of miasma.   There are plenty of factors that could have caused this, but i will trt to add the ones i think have caused this:

- He was working with Rough Onyx. (but never actually got started)
- He was not assigned to any burrows.
- He was "content".
- He had an assigned bedroom.
- He was NOT in any strange mood.
- The fort was not in lack of food, water or booze.

Note 1:
I recently discovered his corpse (although it was visible that it was still in the gem workshop. The fact that it was "dehydrated" probably explains the miasma). So, why would my r gemcrafter isolate himself inside of his workshop?

Note 2:

His workshop layout:

```
WWWWWWW
W...ppW
W...pp
W...ppW
WWWWWWW
```

p = gem stockpile (was full that time)
W = Wall
. = workshop tile

Comment: You should be including every detail that you think might have contributed to this problem, not require us to ask for everything.

Comment: Sure thing. Ill try to include some factors then.

Comment: was he in a mood?

Comment: Was he assigned to a burrow? Dorfs will (un)happily starve and dehydrate to death rather than disobey a burrow assignment.

Comment: Nope. No burrows. Gonna add that to the list.

Comment: Does your announcements log (also viewable in `[dwarf fortress folder]/gamelog.txt`) mention this dwarf? Job cancellations, perhaps?

Comment: was his workshop extremely cluttered?

Comment: Was the door forbidden?

Comment: I bet he is entamaphobic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When setting up a workshop, Dwarf Fortress shows you which tiles are impassible.

If you haven't installed a tileset, the default is to use a light green X for passable tiles, and a dark green X for impassible tiles. (If you are using a tileset, remember that the middle square of every workshop is passable, so when designating a workshop, the passable tiles are those that look like the center tile.)

In the case of the gem workshop, the layout is:

x x **x**
x x **x**
x x **x**

So all three tiles on the right of the workshop are impassible, which explains why your dwarf was unable to exit.

While the layout differs for each type of workshop, once you understand how Dwarf Fortress indicates impassible tiles, you can see when setting up a workshop where a dwarf can enter or leave the workshop, and where they can't, so you can easily look up in-game which tiles are impassible, and avoid setting up a workshop that a dwarf can't escape from, or setting up a workshop with inefficient stockpile locations (e.g. a stockpile to the right of a gem workshop is less efficient, because the dwarf has to walk around the impassible tiles to get to the stockpile).

Comment: Better explained than me own answer... And yeah, im a lazy noob, so im running the appropriate software, and running a texture pack. That prolly explains why i didnt see the "you cant walk there" squares. Thanksies!

Comment: @user37332 It's not really obvious even in vanilla the first time you see it...it's not shown in bold, as above in my post, it's just light green and dark green, so I know I had problems at first telling that the dark green meant impassible. I expect most tilesets will also have a difference, but, as in vanilla, it may not be obvious which is which. The center tile is always passable, so whichever of the two tile designs used when placing workshops doesn't look like the center will be the impassible one.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem:

When a dwarf builds a Jewelers workshop with only a single 1 tile exit to the east, he becomes stuck, since a part of the workshop blocks his path to the exit. I'm not sure what part that is myself, but from now on, im building 5x5 rooms with workshops in the middle, surrounded by stockpiles.

Comment: If I remember correctly, jewelers workshops are a straight line of the 3 east blocks.